# Paging Not Working in ext.js grid, Binded with Ajax Call

Tags: .net, ajax, c#-4.0, extjs

I am able to bind the grid with the ajax call but, i am not able to figure out how to make paging work.
I have also set the page size of the store still..
This is what i have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Attach to onDOMReady event
    Ext.onReady(onReady);

    function onReady() {

        //Define the model for Ext User Grid.
        Ext.define('ExtUserGridModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            id: 'UserId',
            fields: [{ name: 'UserId', type: 'int' }, { name: 'UserName', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'EmailId', type: 'string' }, { name: 'IsAdmin', type: 'bool' },
    { name: 'UserFName', type: 'string' }, { name: 'UserLname', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'PhoneNo', type: 'string' }, { name: 'DateOfBirth', type: 'string'}]
        });

        //data geting method for Ext User Grid
        var ExtUserStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            remoteSort: true,
            model: 'ExtUserGridModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'ExtUsersGrid.aspx/GetExtUsers',
                headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    //totalProperty: 'd.totalCount',
                    root: 'd.userData'
                },
                // sends single sort as multi parameter
                simpleSortMode: true
            }
        });

        // Create Ext User Grid to display data from store
        var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            store: ExtUserStore, // Our store
            defaults: {
                flex: 1
            },
            disableSelection: true,
            loadMask: true,
            title: 'Ext Users Grid',
            columns: [ // Grid columns
                {dataIndex: 'UserName', header: 'User Name' },
                { dataIndex: 'EmailId', header: 'EmailId', width: 250 },
                { dataIndex: 'IsAdmin', header: 'IsAdmin' },
                { dataIndex: 'UserFName', header: 'First Name' },
                { dataIndex: 'UserLname', header: 'Last Name' },
                { dataIndex: 'PhoneNo', header: 'User PhoneNo' },
                { dataIndex: 'DateOfBirth', header: 'Birth Date', flex: 1}],
            renderTo: Ext.get('content'),
            // paging bar on the bottom
            bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                store: ExtUserStore,
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: 'Displaying Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: "No Records to display"
            })
        });
```

**Server Side Code**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public static Object GetExtUsers(String page, String limit)
    {
        //String page, String limit
        var extUserData = SampleDataManager.GetExtUsers();
        var result = new DataSet
        {
            userData = extUserData.Select(x => new ExtUserData
        {
            UserName = x.UserName,
            IsAdmin = ((Boolean)x.IsAdmin),
            EmailId = x.EmailId,
            UserFName = x.UserFName,
            UserLname = x.UserLname,
            PhoneNo = x.PhoneNo,
            DateOfBirth = x.DateOfBirth
        }),
            totalCount = extUserData.Count()
        };

        return result;
    }
  }
}

class DataSet
{
    public IQueryable<ExtUserData> userData { get; set; }
    public Int32 totalCount { get; set; }
}

class ExtUserData
{
    public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String EmailId { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public String UserFName { get; set; }
    public String UserLname { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public String DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

The jSON response i Get is

```
{"d":{"userData":[{"UserId":0,"UserName":"Rex","EmailId":"Vinaypratap.bhadauria@intsof.com","IsAdmin":true,"UserFName":"Vinay Pratap","UserLname":"Singh","PhoneNo":"8557989106","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"},{"UserId":0,"UserName":"Ramit","EmailId":"Ramit.gulati@intsof.com","IsAdmin":false,"UserFName":"Ramit","UserLname":"Gulati","PhoneNo":"1234567894","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"},{"UserId":0,"UserName":"Haider","EmailId":"Haider.hussain@intsof.com","IsAdmin":false,"UserFName":"Haider","UserLname":"Hussain","PhoneNo":"1234567894","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"},{"UserId":0,"UserName":"BHupendra","EmailId":"Bhupendra.shukla@intsof.com","IsAdmin":false,"UserFName":"Bhupendra","UserLname":"Shukla","PhoneNo":"1234567894","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"},{"UserId":0,"UserName":"Anirudh","EmailId":"anirudh.agarwal@intsof.com","IsAdmin":false,"UserFName":"Anirudh","UserLname":"Agarwal","PhoneNo":"1234567894","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"},{"UserId":0,"UserName":"Sachin","EmailId":"Sachin.Singh@intsof.com","IsAdmin":false,"UserFName":"Sachin","UserLname":"Singh","PhoneNo":"1234567894","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"},{"UserId":0,"UserName":"Akash","EmailId":"Akash.malhotr@intsof.com","IsAdmin":false,"UserFName":"Akash","UserLname":"malhotr","PhoneNo":"1234567894","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"},{"UserId":0,"UserName":"Gautam","EmailId":"Gautam.bharadwaj@intsof.com","IsAdmin":false,"UserFName":"Gautam","UserLname":"Bharadwaj","PhoneNo":"1234567894","DateOfBirth":"03/29/1991"}],"totalCount":8}}
```

The grid Shows all the records and the pages tells it has showing given no of records Ie:5

Comment: Describe "not working". Are you not getting back data from the server? Not getting back the range of date you expect? You'll need to elaborate on what the problem actually is.

Comment: @existdissolve yes i am getting the data from the server, and the grid is getting binded properly, just i am not able to apply paging on it.

Comment: Are the paging params getting sent through to the server correctly? You should see a page param, a limit param, and a start param.

Comment: Also remember that you are technically responsible for providing the paged results. All that Ext JS does is provide the parameters that define which part of the result set should be returned. The server is responsible for creating that result set and returning it. So if you're querying a DB, for example, it's the server-side code's job to apply the paging params received from Ext JS to the query in order to return the proper result set.

Comment: @existdissolve yes all that is fine, as per as the documentations of ext.js(sencha) they asked to give the page size to the store and it will handle it,  i have done a lot of r&d after that, it may also be case of some missing script. i will post if i solved it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this

change the reader like this

```
        var ExtUserStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoLoad: true,
            //autoLoad: { params: { start: 0, limit: 5} },
            pageSize: 5,
            model: 'ExtUserGridModel',
            proxy: {
                enablePaging: true, // replaces PagingMemoryProxy functionality
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'ExtUsersGrid.aspx/GetExtUsers',
                headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    totalProperty: 'd.totalCount',
                    root: 'd.userData',
                    model: 'ExtUserGridModel',
                    id: 'd.userData.UserId'
                }
            }
        });
```

And server Side code like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public static Object GetExtUsers(Int32 page, Int32 limit)
    {
        //String page, String limit
        Int32 skipRows = (page - 1) * limit < 0 ? 0 : (page - 1) * limit;
        var extUserData = SampleDataManager.GetExtUsers();
        var RequiredData = extUserData.OrderBy(x => x.UserId).Skip(skipRows).Take(limit);
        var result = new DataSet
        {
            userData = RequiredData.Select(x => new ExtUserData
        {
            UserName = x.UserName,
            IsAdmin = ((Boolean)x.IsAdmin),
            EmailId = x.EmailId,
            UserFName = x.UserFName,
            UserLname = x.UserLname,
            PhoneNo = x.PhoneNo,
            DateOfBirth = x.DateOfBirth
        }),
            totalCount = extUserData.Count()
        };
        return result;
    }
    }
}

class DataSet
{
    public Int32 totalCount { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<ExtUserData> userData { get; set; }
}

class ExtUserData
{
    public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String EmailId { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public String UserFName { get; set; }
    public String UserLname { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public String DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you know that when answering your own bounty the bounty get lost? That is simply because you cannot assign the bounty to your own.

Answer (score 2):

Just some hints (some are micro some are best practice):

- you don't need 'd' and I recommend you to turn your selection-result into a list by calling `toList()`. Dunno where your wrapper object `d` is coming from, I use Json.Net in all of my projects.
- a reader does not have a model cfg property. If you define one on your store, the store will apply it to the proxy for you. In short, you only need the model at storelevel
- [enablePaging](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory-cfg-enablePaging) is only valid for a [Ext.data.Proxy.Memory](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy)
- `id` on the reader should be named `idProperty` [API-link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-idProperty)
- I guess you should rename `page` to `start` and use this instead of `skipRows` see the comment below

Where did you submit the arguments `Int32 page` and `Int32 limit` and why do you calculate skip rows? For me it looks like you are using ordinary paging with take & skip. This is already provided by the paging toolbar. You should need to do nothing at all. Ok, you need to apply the toolbar and configure the pagesize on the store. From that on the pagingtoolbar will apply a `start` and `limit` property to each store request (as long as you don't bypass the pagingtoolbar).

Comment: thanks again, i have applied the changes suggested by you, all this help/explanation was really helpful.

Comment: @Rex You misunderstood me, don't remove it from the query! You just don't need the calculation for skip  as you do here `Int32 skipRows = (page - 1) * limit < 0 ? 0 : (page - 1) * limit;`. The pagingbar already does this for you and will submit it as value of the `start` property. So for paging simply expect `int start, int limit` per default (it is possible to rename the properties, `start` & `limit` are just the default names)